# Getting PHP routing Library to work with Azure App Service?

Tags: php, azure, .htaccess, azure-web-app-service, web-config

I have a PHP app that uses Steampixel\Route for it's routing. I can't get it to work with azure.
I created another azure app service to see if I can get Steampixel\Route or another routing library to work.
Let's say my index.php is the following:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Steampixel\Route;


Route::add('/testroute', 'onTestRoute');
Route::add('/', 'onIndex');
Route::run('/');

function onIndex() {
    echo 'on index route<br/>';
    echo 'go to <a href="/testroute">testRoute</a> to see if routing works';
}

function onTestRoute() {
    echo 'on test route';
}
```

when running this locally, everything works just like it should. But deploying to azure, /testroute gives me a 404 not found error.
I added a web.config to my project root:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="redirect all requests" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" pattern="" ignoreCase="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and also a .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

# enable apache rewrite engine
RewriteEngine on


RewriteBase /

# Deliver the folder or file directly if it exists on the server
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Push every request to index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA]
```

Still nothing. This basic application still can't redirect me to /testroute when deployed on azure.
Anyone know how to get this to work? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am also faced the same issue. Please follow the steps to fix the issue.

After deployment go to your **Azure Portal** and navigate to your **php app** and select **Settings** blade -> **Configurations**.

And Click the **Path Mapping** tab and change your default **physical path** to your **app physical path**.

Eg:

Default physical path – `site/webroot`

Your app physical path – `site/webroot/{appdirectory}`

[image]

Save your changes. It will restart your app and you can check your app it cannot through the route 404 not found error.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Could you please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.